# Magento site not getting launched from outside my LAN

Tags: magento

Secure and Unsecure base url has been set to http://xx.xx.xx.xx/magento/. Where xx.xx.xx.xx is my LAN IP. So  ecommerce magento site  works fine in my local machine  with above mentioned URL.

and my LAN IP is NAT with global IP yy.yy.yy.yy. 
When I launch my magento ecommerce site with global ip( http://yy.yy.yy.yy/magento/) , it route correctly to local ip url (http://xx.xx.xx.xx/magento/) but fails to launch with following error.

Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to xx.xx.xx.xx/magento/.

Please let me know the fix for this issue.

Note: Global ip is pinging withput any issue  . 
      Also I tried to launch global url from outside my LAN Network.
      I can also access just http://yy.yy.yy.yy (WAMP server info)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following steps:

1. Open phpmyadmin.
2. Open core_config_data table.
3. Change value for **value** column to http://yy.yy.yy.yy/magento/ where path = **web/secure/base_url** and path = **web/secure/base_url**.

I hope you are able to understand my point.

Comment: Thanks Mohit ...Same issue exist even after making above changes...Any other fix ?